# How to detect if the "Enable Extension" notification is showing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've built a simple chrome extension for a client that has a windows application. 
He wants to install the extension with the install of the software itself, I've managed to get this done.

I understood that since the install is done externally the user will see this message:

[image]

I also understood that this message will be shown for a limited number of times.

I would like to detect if this message is shown or not, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This will be shown once on first install. If the user accepts, the extension will be activated and will update automatically in future; if the user declines, the extension is blacklisted and will not be installed automatically again.

You can't detect it from the extension, as the extension (as per security measures) is not enabled yet.